# Exception in plugin Lombok in IntelliJ Idea 2020.2

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-lombok-plugin

We have updated our Intellij to the latest build IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-202.6397.94, built on July 27, 2020. we are getting the following error:

```
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Class constructor must not have parameters: de.plushnikov.intellij.plugin.settings.ProjectSettingsPage [Plugin: Lombook Plugin]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateExtensionWithPicoContainerOnlyIfNeeded(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:694)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ConfigurableEP$ClassProducer.createElement(ConfigurableEP.java:422)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ConfigurableEP.createConfigurable(ConfigurableEP.java:329)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper.createConfigurable(ConfigurableWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper.getConfigurable(ConfigurableWrapper.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper.cast(ConfigurableWrapper.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper.getId(ConfigurableWrapper.java:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil.groupConfigurables(ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil.java:267)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil.getConfigurableGroup(ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil.java:129)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil.lambda$getConfigurableGroup$1(ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClearableLazyValue$2.compute(ClearableLazyValue.java:26)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClearableLazyValue.getValue(ClearableLazyValue.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.AtomicClearableLazyValue.getValue(AtomicClearableLazyValue.java:9)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.EpBasedConfigurableGroup.<init>(EpBasedConfigurableGroup.kt:113)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil.getConfigurableGroup(ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil.java:118)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.showSettingsDialog(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:129)
    at de.plushnikov.intellij.plugin.activity.LombokProjectValidatorActivity$SettingsOpeningListener.hyperlinkActivated(LombokProjectValidatorActivity.java:177)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationListener$Adapter.hyperlinkUpdate(NotificationListener.java:23)
    at com.intellij.notification.EventLog$NotificationHyperlinkInfo.navigate(EventLog.java:595)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.EditorHyperlinkSupport.lambda$getLinkNavigationRunnable$0(EditorHyperlinkSupport.java:155)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.EditorHyperlinkSupport$1.mouseReleased(EditorHyperlinkSupport.java:82)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$MyMouseAdapter.runMouseReleasedCommand(EditorImpl.java:3867)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$MyMouseAdapter.mouseReleased(EditorImpl.java:3771)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6650)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6415)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5025)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4857)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4857)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:967)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:904)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:836)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:450)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:802)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:503)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

But same was working with previous IntelliJ versions. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the last Intellij 2020.2 RC build (which fix this bug) on : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2020.2+latest+builds

And be careful to also install last lombok intellij plugin (0.30.1).

This issue is detailed on https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/649 and is not entirelly the fault of the plugin (that's why intellij RC must be also installed)

Obviously this solution should be preferred while waiting for a final Intellij 2020.2.1 version.

More detailled information on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248146 (minimum build version for fix is IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1 RC Build #IC-202.6948.36, built on August 18, 2020)